# Dual of the symmetric algebra of the dual

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and let $S^d(V)$ be the degree $d$ part of the symmetric algebra on $V$.

> Is it true that $S^d(V^*)^*$ is canonically isomorphic to $S^d(V)$?

**What (I think) I know**: $S^d(V^*)$ are homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ on $n=\dim{V}$ variables with coefficients in the base field $k$, because a basis of $V^*$ is given by the $n$ coordinate functions $x_i$ which are the dual basis of any fixed basis for $V$. So the symmetric algebra $S(V^*)$ really *is* the polynomial ring $k[x_1,...,x_n]$, right? (**Remark**: in this description of the symmetric algebra I had to make a choice, namely fixing a basis of $V$.)

**What I don't know**: I think I don't really understand $S(V)$. Should I just think of it as $k[e_1,...,e_n]$, regarding the $e_i$'s just as formal symbols?

In any case, for both descriptions I had to choose a basis. So I was hoping that there may be a canonical isomorphism as in the case of $V\cong (V^*)^*$. Is this true?

Comment: I'll switch around your $V$ and $V^*$ since I find this easier to think about. Over a field of characteristic $0$, there is always a canonical isomorphism $S^d(V^*) \cong (S^d(V))^*$, by symmetrising. For example, if $f, g \in V^*$, the element $fg \in S^d(V^*)$ gets sent to the map $vw \mapsto f(v)g(w) + g(v)f(w)$. But over a field of characteristic small compared to $d$, this isomorphism stops working, for example try to find something in $S^d(V^*)$ mapping to the dot product, where $V$ is a vector space over the field with two elements.